# Arduino not recognizing when a timer reaches 0

Tags: timers, timing, prototype

Alright, so I'm attempting to make a timer that will turn on a light after an hour. Currently I have it set to 5 seconds for testing. What is happening is whenever I start the program it won't recognize when the timer reaches 0.
Here is my code

```
/*
Hour Alarm
An hour long alarm that allows breaks
Created by: Jaxon Reid
Last Edited: 19/5/2017

Pins:
Pin 13 = Led
Pin 2 = Button
*/
int secLeft=5;
const int led=13;
const int button=2;
const int buttonIn=4;
int buttonValue=0;
// Declares the button to reset as 2 and the lightbulb on pin 13
//the secLeft means the seconds until the light turns on and button value is for wether or not the button is pushed

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(2400);
  Serial.print("On  ");
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonIn,INPUT);
}
// makes the led pin an input and opens the channel for the debugger
void loop() {
  int buttonValue=digitalRead(button);
  Serial.println("Checking time");
  if (secLeft<=0) {
    Serial.println("No time remaining");
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    Serial.println("Light On");
    // If the time remaining is 0 then turn on the light
  }
  if (secLeft>0) {
    Serial.println("Time Remaining");
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    secLeft=(secLeft--);
    Serial.println(secLeft);
  }
  if (buttonValue==1) {
    int secLeft=5;
    Serial.println("Reset Timer");
    Serial.println(secLeft);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Whenever I start it up it just starts reading

```
On 5
Checking time
Time remaining
5
Checking time
Time remaining
4
Checking time
Time remaining
3
Checking time
Time remaining
2
Checking time
Time remaining
1
Checking time
Time remaining
0
Checking time
Time remaining
-1
Checking time
Time remaining
-2
```

etc...
So where did I go wrong is what I'm asking.
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is `int secLeft=(secLeft2--);` where you are creating a second variable called `secLeft` within the scope of the `if` block.  Ditch the `int`.  This is the second question I have seen with this issue in the last 30 minutes.  You probably also have the same issue with `secLeft2 `

Comment: Now its not decreasing the secLeft at all

Comment: Noter that you still have an `int secLeft` in the reset section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment and Majenko's answer you are current creating local variables called `secLeft` and `secLeft2` inside the `'if` block.  These take precedence over the ones you have defined globally.  Removing the `in` declarations from inside the `if` block will stop doing that and point you at the globally defined variables.

As to the rest of the code. If you have

```
secLeft=(secLeft2--);
secLeft2=(secLeft);
```

Then that translates to this sequence of instructions

1. Assign `secLeft` with the value of `secLeft2`
2. Decrement `secLeft2`
3. Assign `secLeft2` with the value of `secLeft`

And in the end you do not change anything.

This is because you are using `post-decrement` on `secLeft2`  EG `secLeft2--`.  This is a feature of C style languages.

I am not sure what you are even trying to do at this point.

Comment: Got it thankyou I was thinking it would decrement beforehand

Comment: To get `pre-decrement` you have to do `--secLeft`.  C and C++ have both and they are both useful in their own way.

Answer (score 1):

```
int secLeft=(secLeft2--); 
int secLeft2=(secLeft);
```

You are making 2 new variables there instead of using the existing ones.

Comment: alright how do i fix that?

Comment: By not declaring new variables.

Comment: I have picked this up yesterday i learned C++ yesterday aswell what do i remove?

Comment: Remove the `int` from each line. Also, do you really want to reset secLeft2 to what it was before decrementing it? The second line looks a bit daft.

Comment: Now i just get 5,5,5,5,5 ...

Comment: Edit your question and add your updated code to the end so we can see what you have done.

Comment: I think you are getting muffled with your variables. There is no reason for secLeft2 to even exist.

Comment: I created secleft 2 cause before when i had secLeft=(secLeft--) i was afraid it was looping and reducing it to 0 immetiately btw codes updated

Comment: That format is incorrect but not wrong.  It has a redundant assignment since secLeft-- subtracts one and saves the result.

Answer (score 0):

Besides problems mentioned in other answers, your use of `button` and `buttonIn` variables is messed up.

With `button` equal to 2, the `pinMode(button,OUTPUT)` statement initializes pin 2 to be an output.  Pin 2 is low after reset and `pinMode()` doesn't change it.

When you say `int buttonValue=digitalRead(button);` the low value at pin 2 will be read into `buttonValue`.  In the sketch, `buttonValue` will never be anything but low.

To fix this problem, get rid of `buttonIn`, and in `setup()` use `pinMode(button,INPUT)` to set `button` to be an input, not an output.